# Why is React treating my array as if it were empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am currently creating a full stack application using the MERN stack, and I have come across an issue that I didn't previously have. When I am using the `.map()` function to iterate over my array, *even though* the console logs that my array exists, has a length of 4, and has all the proper elements (they are objects), my array is not iterated over by the `.map()` function.

I also noticed that when I console log `array.length`, I am given zero - although in the previous log I am told that the array has length 4 (which it should).

Below is where I populate my array:

```
getTournaments(){
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/tournament", {
            credentials: 'include',
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then( (response) => response.json())
        .then( (response) => {
            if(response){
                response.map((tournament)=> {
                    this.state.tournaments.push(tournament);
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

I call `getTournaments()` here:

```
componentDidMount(){

        this.getTournaments(); ...
```

This is how I attempted to map over my array:

```
this.state.tournaments.map((tournament,index) => {
   return (<div key={index}> {tournament.title} </div>);
})
```

And finally, my console logs are created when I call my render function. 
Here is the render function :

```
renderSpectatorView(){
        var array = [1,2,3];
        var currentTournaments = this.state.tournaments;
        // console.log(currentTournaments);
        return(
            <div className="page-wrapper">

                            {/* BOOTSTRAP MODAL */}
            {this.state.isAuth ? <Button onClick={this.goToCreate} bsStyle="primary">Create Tournament</Button> : null}
            <div className="tournament-wrapper">
                     {  
                        console.log(this.state.tournaments)}
                       { console.log(this.state.tournaments.length)}

            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I used nearly an identical method (but even more complicated because I iterated over the properties of each object in my array) earlier in my project, so I'm stumped as to why this won't work. My initial thinking was that maybe the render function was being called before I completed fetching the data from my API - but the values log properly.

Should I implement this using promises or async/await so that I ensure that I render only after the data is gathered? Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: What is the value of `response` at the point you attempt the map in your first snippet?

Comment: The problem is `this.state.tournaments.push(tournament);`. You _have_ to use setState to trigger a re-render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `this.state.tournaments.push(tournament);`

You *have* to use setState if you want to trigger an update.
Do something like

```
.then( (response) => {
    if(response){
        this.setState({tournaments: [...this.state.tournaments, ...response.tournaments]});
    }
})
```

The spreading is because it looks like you already have values in `this.state.tournaments` that you wanted to keep, I am not completely sure.
If you are only setting this once you can simple do

```
.then( (response) => {
    if(response){
        this.setState({tournaments: response.tournaments});
    }
})
```

See here for more information [ReactJS Docs: Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

In short; you can *never* mutate state without `setState`, you can't do `this.state.thing = X`, you can't do `this.state.thing.push()`, or anything else. The only way to modify `state` is using `setState`.

Comment: `this.state.tournaments` was just an empty array. I wanted to replace that empty array with whatever tournaments were currently stored in the database, and checking the db for changes each time the page is refreshed/visited (oncomponentdidmount). I switched the state modification to use `setState`, and things worked out fine! Thanks for the answer. I had started moving away from setState after working on things for a few weeks... guess my laziness caught up with me.

Comment: I would go back and look for anywhere else you might not have used it. Things may work by coincidence without setState, as many other things can trigger a component re-render. You'll probably _eventually_ find obscure and illusive bugs if you have cases like this. Since you're just setting it once you can ignore the first part of my answer and just use the simpler second example. Glad to help

Comment: Agreed - that's exactly what I was thinking. Save myself some future headaches.